# qml project: SIGFPE Arithmetic exception

Tags: android, qt, qml

I have application crash on this line, then run app on Android 4.4.2 x86 emulator:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
```

Exception is: `SIGFPE Arithmetic exception`

emptyQml.pro

```
QT += qml quick
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += main.cpp
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine; // <============================== exception is here
    //engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

This is a minimal example. Real app crashes on client device with Android 4.4.2.

In GoolePlay console there are crash reports for Android 4.4:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary (Runtime.java:365) 
  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary (System.java:526) 
  at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtLoader.loadApplication (QtLoader.java:244) 
  at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtLoader.startApp (QtLoader.java:647) 
  at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivityLoader.onCreate (QtActivityLoader.java:181) 
  at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.onCreateHook (QtActivity.java:266) 
  at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.onCreate (QtActivity.java:273) 
  at com.approvalmax.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:91) 
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:5426) 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1105) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2269) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2363) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:161) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1265) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:157) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5356) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1265) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1081) 
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
```

qt: `5.8`
ndk: `android-ndk-r10e`
jdk: `jdk1.8.0_101`
ant: `apache-ant-1.9.7`

Any ideas?

Comment: Check out https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-39294 and https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-66726